# Docker mysql environment

Tags: php, mysql, docker, alpine-linux

I have a Dockerfile that is based FROM `php:alpine` and I'm trying to add mysql to the build.

```
FROM php:alpine

COPY test-data/ /var/www/

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    mysql

# Composer
RUN curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin/ --filename=composer
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

WORKDIR /var/www
```

My problem is after successfully building, I tried and run the container with the mysql environment overrides but I cant login to mysql within the container.

```
$ docker run -e MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead -e MYSQL_USER=homestead -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -ti --rm idecardo /bin/sh
```

Testing mysql login fails

```
$ mysql -uroot -p # with password "secret"
```

Comment: Without actually running the container, i cant know for sure, but it is almost certainly bc mysql is service that you installed but did not start.  The docker standard is one process per container.  Instead of  adding mysql,to ur container add another mysql container.

Comment: As a beginner, my article on a simple LAMP setup with Docker and Docker Compose might help you visualize how you organize services in Docker - https://bitpress.io/simple-approach-using-docker-with-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are newbie - always try to learn by copying ready working code over and breaking down what is being done in that code.

For Docker:

1. You can see the docker repository for mysql - https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/
   Under description section you will see links to various docker files for different MySQL versions.
2. Take one of them as a source for your inspiration, for example the link to  8.0/Dockerfile: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/fc3e856313423dc2d6a8d74cfd6b678582090fc7/8.0/Dockerfile
3. Notice that after mysql installation instructions in that dockerfile there is Entrypoint and CMD instructions.

In general:

Since you want php and mysql to work from docker - my advise is for you to see about docker-compose. Docker containers can be run in a variety of ways and docker-compose allows you to launch several docker containers, share some folders between them. In that scenario you would want to launch separate mysql container and separate php container, share host data folders between them and launch your code.

Also, watch some video tutorials online - they explain in details the basics of what docker is all about and how it works.